# Release group and Release Strategy fields not filled in Service Entry Sheet(SES)

Tags: abap, sap-erp, dynpro

I'm having a problem with transaction code `ML81N` and `ML85`.

Both programs works as expected, though, there is a problem with the release strategy not being assigned to new orders.

I followed [this](https://www.guru99.com/release-procedures-for-purchasing-documents.html) guide, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I did everything the tutorial explained. Only difference are the values I set, such as release code, release group, etc...

Is there something more I need to do?

---

Edit - Posted screenshots of my full configuration

---

Transaction: `OLMSRV` => `Define Release Procedure for Service Entry Sheet` => `Release Groups`

[image]

---

Transaction: `OLMSRV` => `Define Release Procedure for Service Entry Sheet` => `Release Codes`

[image]

---

Transaction: `OLMSRV` => `Define Release Procedure for Service Entry Sheet` => `Release Indicator`

[image]

---

Transaction: `OLMSRV` => `Define Release Procedure for Service Entry Sheet` => `Release Strategies`

[image]

---

Transaction: `OLMSRV` => `Define Release Procedure for Service Entry Sheet` => `Release Strategies` => `Classification`

[image]

---

Transaction: `CL02`

[image]

---

Transaction: `CL02`

[image]

---

Transaction: `CT04`

[image]

---

Transaction: `CT04`

[image]

---

Transaction: `CT04`

[image]

---

*Class name:* `RILASCIOPRESTAZION`

*Characteristic Name*: `RILASCIOPRESTAZIONI`

*Release Group*: `Z1`

*Release Code*: `Z1`

---

Comment: I am not sure if this question is really on-topic here on stackoverflow. It seems like a question for SAP consultants, not for developers. Unfortunately I don't think there is a better stack exchange site for questions like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this question is off-topic as pointed out by @Philipp in the comment, and I understand that, I'll post an answer anyway as it resolved my issue.

It turns out there's a problem in the program's code of txcode `ML81N` which would reset whatever was set inside function module `EXIT_SAPLMLSR_010`(user exit => `SRVESSR - Set entry sheet header data`).

SAP-NOTE **[2132444](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2132444)** solved the issue.